# How to resolve? cvs [checkout aborted]

Tags: cvs

I randomly get this error during CVS checkout

cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot rename file CVS/Entries.Backup to CVS/Entries: No such file or directory

Can someone suggest how to resolv this problem and avoid in future? Each time I checkout in new directory.